# .NET Core - Adding Scaffolded Item "There was an Error creating the DbContext to get the model"

Tags: c#, .net

Whenever I attempt to create a new scaffolded item for my project, I receive an error stating

[There was an error creating the DbContect instance to get the model
No Parameterless constructor defined for this object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULffO.jpg)

I have attempted to rebuild my project, and I have had success generating scaffolds prior, however for some reason when doing so now I haven't had any success. No alterations have been done to my context class since I last added a new scaffolded item.

I have attempted to create an empty constructor in my model however it still tosses the same error. Below you will find my code for my model I'm trying to scaffold, and my context.

```cs
namespace HRIAT.Models
{

    public class Credential
    {

        public Credential() { }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string credentialName { get; set; }
        public FundingSource credentialFundingSource { get; set; }
        public string credentialType { get; set; }
        public float credentialCost { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Employee> ec { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Context class:

```cs
namespace HRIAT.Models
{
    public class HRIATContext : DbContext
    {
        public HRIATContext(DbContextOptions<HRIATContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }


        public DbSet<FundingSource> FundingSource { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Credential> Credential { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

        public DbSet<EmployeesCredentials> EmployeeCredential { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeesCredentials>().HasKey(c => new { c.CredentialID, c.employeeNum });
        }

        public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if the entities of your project do not contains an empty constructor. EntityFramework needs the empty constructor to instantiate the entity and maps properties of schema.

If you needs protect the entity classes, use the protected constructor, example:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    protected Person() { }

}
```

Comment: Are you referring to an empty constructor within my model .cs files? I haven't had constructors in those prior yet I was capable of generating scaffolds earlier.

Comment: I did add the empty constructor to my class, however I still receive the same error actually.

Comment: Should be an empty constructor in the class model. Remember the empty constructor is implicit in C#, but if you include a parameterized constructor, the empty constructor ceases to exist, if the class has a constructor with parameters it requires to the person to instantiate the object to inclusion of parameters. More like you said it did not work, edit the question including more information and source code therefore based only on the error message can not say.